# exports.example()= functions.https.onRequest((request, response){} in dialogflow v2

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

How can i get request object in dialogflow v2.

I have the following code in dialogflow v1, How i should use in dialogflow v2. I want to use request.body in dialogflow v2. Can anyone help me with this?

```
exports.example()= functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {  
   const app = new App({request, response});  
   console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));   
   console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is taken from one of [Dialogflow's samples](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-bike-shop-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) up on Github. Here's the Dialogflow reference docs for [WebhookClient](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client#webhookclientendresponses). There's also a [V1 to V2 migration guide](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide) available in the docs as well.

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, 
response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function hours (agent) {
    if (currentlyOpen()) {
      agent.add(`We're open now! We close at 5pm today.`);
    } else {
      agent.add(`We're currently closed, but we open every weekday at 9am!`);
    }
  }
```